# zf2 fieldset ArrayCollection is empty while it is expected to be filled

Tags: php, forms, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, entity-relationship

I have a form ProductForm and inside that form I called base fieldset ProductFieldset and inside ProductFieldset I called CategoryFieldset. The relationship between the entities is OneToOne.

Here are the Entities:

```
namespace Trunk\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CategoryId", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $categoryid;

   /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Trunk\Entity\Category", mappedBy="product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoryid", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $category;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->category  = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCategoryid()
    {
        return $this->categoryid;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $categoryid
     */
    public function setCategoryid($categoryid)
    {
        $this->categoryid = $categoryid;
    } 

    public function addCategory(Category $category)
    {
        if (! $this->category->contains($category)) {
            $this->category->add($category);
        }
        return $this;
    } 
    public function removeCategory(Category $category)
    {
        if ($this->category->contains($category)) {
            $this->category->removeElement($category);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
}
```

And here is the Category entity:

```
namespace Trunk\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ParentId", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $parentid = '0';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

The result after the submission of the form is:

```
object(Trunk\Entity\Product)[480]
  protected 'id' => null
  protected 'categoryid' => null
  protected 'category' => 
    object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[482]
      private 'elements' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

I have used Doctrine hydrators however there is no results.

Could you give me some ideas why is that always empty ? Thank you in advance!

> More code

```
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url . '/admin/holiday/add/bg');
$form->prepare();
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
$holiday = $form->get('product');
echo $this->formElement($holiday->get('category')->get('categoryid'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Here it is the add action in the controller:

```
public function addAction()
{
    $oRequest = $this->getRequest();

    if ($oRequest->isPost()) {
        $aPost = $oRequest->getPost('product');

        $this->productForm->setData($oRequest->getPost());

        if ($this->productForm->isValid()) {

            try {
                $result = $this->productService->addProduct($this->productForm->getData());

                if ($result) {
                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('trunk', array('controller' => 'product', 'action' => 'edit', 'id' => $result->getLang(), 'param' => $result->getId()));
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                // some DB error happened,, log it and let the user know
                exit;
            }
        }
    }

return new ViewModel(array(
    'form' => $this->productForm,
));
```

}

The code below is used to hydrate the objects in the CategoryFieldset

```
$this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($this->getObjectManager(), 'Trunk\Entity\Category'))
        ->setObject(new Category());
```

And here it is how I add CategoryFieldset in the ProductFieldset

```
$this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Trunk\Form\CategoryFieldset',
        'name' => 'category'
    ));
```

***Edit 1:***

ManyToOne relationship in ProductEntity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Trunk\Entity\Category", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoryid", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $category;
```

OneToMany relationship in CategoryEntity

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Trunk\Entity\Product", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $products;
```

I got the following error

> Could not resolve type of column "id" of class "Trunk\Entity\Category"

I checked the code in PersistHelper.php getTypeOfColumn function and I found out that it is looking for joinColumns.

Comment: Did you prepare your form with $form->prepare() in the view ?

Comment: Hi @Hooli, I've added the code from the view and the controller. Do you think I am missing something?

Comment: You might want to review the mapping declaration of your `Product#categories` . You're declaring this as a strict one-to-one relation to a catgory (i.e a product has one category, each category has one product only). Yet you're talking about collections, which suggest this might be a many-to-one relationship.

Comment: Hi @Fge I have fixed the relationship as you notice I was using the wrong one to one. I need many to one. I will add these changes above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is resolved!

To fix the relationship error that I posted last I had to use this annotation in the ProductEntity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Trunk\Entity\Category", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="CategoryId", referencedColumnName="Id")
 */
protected $category;
```

In another words I changed the reference column name from "id" to Id(case sensitive).

I hope this question and examples will help out other colleagues as well.